# MySQL select group by and Not Null

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this table

```
    CREATE TABLE title
    (`id` int, `title` varchar(16), `author` varchar(6), `city` varchar(8), `year` int, `pageId` varchar(4), `page` int);

   INSERT INTO title
       (`id`, `title`, `year`, `pageId`, `page`)
   VALUES
       (1, 'A', 1951, '20', 1),
       (2, 'A',  1951, '99', 2),
       (3, 'A',  1951, '101', 3),
       (4, 'A',  1951, NULL, 4),
       (5, 'B',  1937, '200', 76),
       (6, 'B',  1937, '201', 73),

       (7, 'C',  1951, '4', 32),
       (8, 'C',  1951, NULL, 32),

    (9, 'D',  1937, '6', 74)
;
```

I need select id #6 and #9

select group by title  and if pageId not null in any record

Comment: You want to `group by` on what basis? `group by` is used only when we're using aggregate function in our `select` statement.

Comment: Can you explain in detail by adding desired result set.

Comment: i need to select title with pageId  no null in this case i dont need title A because pageId in #4 is null but i need title B because no null and select from B #6

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
SELECT 
   t1.id, t1.title, t1.year, t1.pageId, t1.page
  FROM 
   title t1
  WHERE 
    t1.pageId IS NOT NULL AND (t1.id = 6 OR t1.id = 9) 
  GROUP BY t1.title
```

Comment: i have tried on my machine, it is working fine. can you please what is error you getting.

check attached screenshot:: tinyurl.com/yy5gee9a

Comment: I guess because this is MySQL.  You can try to run it in any other dbms and see if it runs or not.  The code doesn't make sense logically.  Any non-aggregated columns must be in `GROUP BY`.  In this case, if you grouping by `t1.title`, if there are multiple `ti.pageId`, which one is included?